# How to find Max and its index in vector in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Please have a look at the following code. I've tried using max_element function and find function to complete the task, but shows segmentation error, **when compiled**. I've checked it is not out of bound. Kindly help me out, Also, if possible kindly suggest me some resource on C++ I know badics, I'm having difficulty in the STL part.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
double bag( int w, vector<int> values,vector<int> weights){
    int index, ma;
    double W1=0.0;
    double V=0.0;
    while(W1<=w)
    {
ma=*max_element(values.begin(), values.end())   ;
auto it = find(values.begin(), values.end(), ma);
index = distance(values.begin(),it);

if(w-W1>=weights[index])
{
V=V+values[index];
W1=W1+weights[index];
}

else 
{
    V=V+values[index]*(w-W1)/weights[index];
    }
    
    values.erase(it);
    weights.erase(it);
    }
    return V;
}
int main() {
  int n;
  int w;
  double ans;
  std::cin >> n >> w;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }
    cout<<values[n-1];
    ans = bag(w,values,weights);
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are "dereferencing" what is returning from `max_element` without checking if it is `values.end()`, which must not be "dereferenced".

The loop condition `while(W1<=w)` should be `while(!values.empty() && W1<=w)`.

Also `weights.erase(it);` is invalid because `it` is an iterator for `values`, not `weights`.

```
values.erase(it);
weights.erase(it);
```

should be

```
weights.erase(std::next(weights.begin(), std::distance(values.begin(), it)));
values.erase(it);
```